# How do I prevent getting several alerts for a calendar event?

Tags: icloud, email, calendar

I am a Helicopter Pilot, the company I work for utilizes acuity scheduling for scheduling flights, all the pilots utilize google calendar but I am the only one with the problem. So we had a flight scheduled at 7:15. Just before the appointment I received 3 email alerts from iCloud and 1 alert from google.

Why do I get several alerts and how can I stop this?

[image]

Comment: Nice, I've edited your question a bit to make it more clear. If we start with numbering the mails with 1 from the top, which are the four notification mails?

Comment: FWIW - I think the email alerts are from Google Calendar, not iCloud. I also believe you can turn off email reminders at <https://calendar.google.com>.

Comment: So the number 1 (top) email, which actually contains 3 of the same alerts, is from iCloud, then number 2 is the same alert, only from google. Then 4 & 5 is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the notification behavior (disable) in Google Calendar.

1. On your computer, open Google Calendar.
2. In the top right, click Settings Settings  and then Settings.
3. On the left, under "Settings for my calendars," click the calendar you want to change and then Calendar settings.
4. Under "Event notifications" or "All-day event notifications":
5. To edit a notification, choose if you'd like to receive a notification or an email.
6. To delete a notification, click Remove notification

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en